# running different versions of a kernel

Tags: virtualization

Now the biggest disadvantage in running operating system virtualization is that the user is only able to run the same operating system on all virtualized instances. At least is it possible to run different versions of the same kernel ?

Comment: Are you really sure you want to run different versions of a kernel? Linux kernels are mostly upward compatible: a newer kernel can run applications running on older kernels.

Comment: And you could even use `chroot` to have an old "distribution" inside a newer one. So you could use `chroot` to e.g. have an old libc inside.

Comment: is chroot really a operating system virtualization  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The kernel is in charge of managing and abstracting real resources (CPU, devices). So you cannot have several [kernels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_%28computing%29) at once on a machine.

What you might have is an [hypervisor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypervisor) (which is a sort-of kernel), providing multiple [virtual machines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine). On each of them, you would run a different kernel. You could for example use [Xen](http://www.xen.org/) as an hypervisor (and you could nest them).

Comment: i ask whether is it possible to run different versions of the same kernel through operating system virtualization?

Comment: Some hypervisors (e.g. Xen) can be nested (e.g. you run two Xen-s under another Xen); other can't. It is also a matter of system configuration (and also hardware abilities).